# is "I entered the lift" correct?

Tags: sentence-choice, idiomatic-language

- I entered the lift.
- I entered into the lift
- I entered in the lift
- I got in the lift

Which one of those sentences is the most appropriate?

I'd also like to know what is the difference between a lift and elevator ?

Comment: For your second question, look up the word in a dictionary such as [this one](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/lift). The most natural-sounding one (to my non-native ear) is "I got into the elevator/lift.". If you elect to sound more formal, use "I entered the elevator/lift.". Another viable option would be "I got in the elevator/lift.". "Enter" implies "in", so it'd make little sense to say "enter in(to) something".

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have stated, a lift and an elevator refer to the same machine. *Lift* is British English and *elevator* is North American. I'm from the USA so I'm not as familiar with the term lift, but native speakers rarely use the preposition "in" when speaking about the elevator. We say

> I got ***on*** the elevator

When entering doors, we use "entered" or "went/got in" when talking about a room or closet. But the lift/elevator is a *machine* so "got on" is more appropriate.

The machine with chairs that carry skiers to the top of a mountain is called a "ski lift" or "chair lift" and is often referred to simply as "the lift." We also use "got on the lift" here.

Answer (score 1):

`Lift:  BrE. A platform or compartment housed in a shaft for raising and lowering people or things to different levels.'

```
Elevator: North American term for lift.
```

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lift
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/elevator

I entered the lift

I got into the lift